# htaccess rule for restrict not logged in user to access direct pdf link in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, pdf, url-rewriting, restriction

Htaccess rule for restrict not logged in user(cookie based) to access direct pdf link in Wordpress. I have tried the rules to restrict access on local host it worked partially on it but when applied on the live website rules not seems to work. The code i have tried mentioned below.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*cookie_name.*$
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/contact-sales/ [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Where did you put this, in the context of the already existing WP rewriting?

Comment: yes. In htaccess file on root folder

Comment: I meant, where within the existing .htaccess content.

Comment: I tired with different location on the file top, bottom, after the RewriteBase

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try below snippet

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*uploads/.*
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
  RewriteRule \.(pdf)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried this code. Working on localhost but not on the staging server

Comment: You need to update the file at root of WP or which Server do you use, check whether it is compatible with htaccess file. Or debug more why the environment causing the issue being execute htacess code.

Comment: the site hosted on siteground and they say issue not on there end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).